# objective C add keys to dictionary

Tags: objective-c

In the code snippet below you can find my current implementantion where the function return an array with data. I'm looking for a way to return an `NSDictionary` instead with `"IPv4"`, `"IPv6"` keys and values correspondingly.

```
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *) addressesFromService:(NSNetService *)service
{
//    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *addresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    
    char addressBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    
    for (NSData *data in service.addresses) {
        memset(addressBuffer, 0, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

        typedef union {
            struct sockaddr sa;
            struct sockaddr_in ipv4;
            struct sockaddr_in6 ipv6;
        } ip_socket_address;

        ip_socket_address *socketAddress = (ip_socket_address *)[data bytes];

        if (socketAddress && (socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET || socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET6)) {
            const char *addressStr = inet_ntop(
                socketAddress->sa.sa_family,
                (socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET ? (void *)&(socketAddress->ipv4.sin_addr) : (void *)&(socketAddress->ipv6.sin6_addr)),
                addressBuffer,
                sizeof(addressBuffer)
            );

//            if (addressStr) {
//                NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:addressStr];
//                [addresses addObject:address];
//            }
            if (addressStr) {
                NSString *key = AF_INET ? @"IPv4" : @"IPv6";
                result[key] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:addressStr];
            }
        }
    }

//    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:addresses];
    return [result copy];
}
```

Comment: What is your question here? If you want to replace `NSString *address` with `NSDictionary *dictionary`, why exactly can't you do that?

Comment: I added *dictionary but I am trying to figure out how to add keys to the dictionary. I am trying to have format ipv4: "123.43.2.4", ipv6: "r4:5y::53"
currently all I have is 123.43.2.4, r4:5y::53

Comment: If you want a dictionary instead of an array then create a dictionary instead of creating an array (NSMutableDictionary instead of NSMutableArray). What issue are you having trying to create a dictionary?

Comment: @HangarRash I am new to objective-c The issue that I currently have is that I would like to add keys to my return result currently I return the following ```123.43.2.4, r4:5y::53```. I would like to return like this ```ipv4: "123.43.2.4", ipv6: "r4:5y::53" ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the method/function signature to match the return type (`NSDictionary *` instead of `NSArray *`) but for the snippet you provided you merely need to introduce a mutable dictionary right prior to the loop body:

```objc
NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSData *data in service.addresses) {
...
```

And then replace the part where you add values like this:

```objc
if (addressStr) {
    NSString *key = socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET ? @"IPv4" : @"IPv6";
    result[key] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:addressStr];
}
```

If you want to return an immutable version of the dictionary, don't forget to make a copy:

```objc
return [result copy];
```

Comment: I just updated the code in the question. This what needed. Only have 1 issue. the code only return ````"addresses": {
    "IPv4": "fe80::b09c:4aff:fec6:72e4"
  },````
It should return both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: @JerrySeigle my bad. `AF_INET` needs to be compared against current `socketAddress->sa.sa_family` under the `if` branch. I fixed it in the answer for the reference

Comment: @JerrySeigle Also, from the edited answer, don't forget to change `+ (NSArray<NSString *> *) addressesFromService` signature return type (`+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *) addressesFromService`)